# Unable to Close two popups together in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF I am showing two popups together on click event of a button inside a Grid. Now whenever I click anywhere outside of a popup either on 'second popup' or 'in area excluding two popups' other popup disappears. My requirement is both popups should disappear together and they should not disappear when clicked on other popup, & they both should hide together when clicked anywhere apart from two popup area.

Code I am trying:-

```
popup1.PlacementTarget = clickedButton;
popup1.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
popup1.HorizontalOffset = -435.5;
popup1.VerticalOffset = -20;
popup1.IsOpen = true;

popup2.PlacementTarget = clickedButton;
popup2.VerticalOffset = 9;
popup2.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: Did you try to set the `StaysOpen` property to `true`?

Comment: Yes for both popups in  xaml file, I've set the 'StaysOpen' property to false itself.

Answer (score 0):

Along with your code,add below function

```
  public List<Popup> ActivePopups = new List<Popup>();

  public void AddActivePopup(ref Popup ActivePopup)
  {
    try
      {
        if (ActivePopup.IsOpen == true)
            ActivePopups.Add(ActivePopup);
      }
    catch (Exception ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
   }
```

and add this line after popup2.IsOpen = true,

```
  AddActivePopup(popup2);
```

Comment: try/catch with `throw ex` doesn't do anything and only hides information of exception. Also `Popup` is a class so `ref` is not needed.

Comment: I've already set 'IsOpen' property to 'true' for both popup. I don't see any additional  benefit here of adding both popups to List.